# Fields in custom serializers.Serializer

Tags: python, django, api

My code:

```
class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    isActive = serializers.BooleanField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Project.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.id = validated_data.get('id', instance.id)
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.isActive = validated_data.get('isActive', instance.isActive)
        return instance

class ProjectsCreateSerializer(ProjectsSerializer):enter code here
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name')
```

Why is

```
class Meta: 
    fields = ('name')
```

not working? I see all object, not only name.

I expect the output of fields in `ProjectsCreateSerializer` to be `{"name": ""}` but the actual output is `{"name": "","isActive": false}`